# Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.Integer

Tags: java

I keep receiving this exception in my code Exception in thread "main"

> java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.Integer

I do not know how to fix my format conversion. Help would be appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class SoftwareSales {
public static void main(String[] args) {
// This program displays the amount of discount (if any) and the total amount of the purchase after the discount.

    String userInput;
    String userOutput;
    double packagePrice = 99;
    int userNumberOfPackages;
    double discount = 0;
    double subTotal = 0;
    double total = 0;

    userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Enter how many packages you are buying" );
    userNumberOfPackages = Integer.parseInt( userInput );

    if ( userNumberOfPackages < 10){
        subTotal = packagePrice * userNumberOfPackages;
        discount = 0;
        total = subTotal - discount;

    } else if ( userNumberOfPackages < 20 ){
        subTotal = packagePrice * userNumberOfPackages;
        discount = ( (double)20/100) * subTotal;
        total = subTotal - discount;

    } else if ( userNumberOfPackages < 50 ){
        subTotal = packagePrice * userNumberOfPackages;
        discount = ( (double)30/100) * subTotal;
        total = subTotal - discount;

    } else if ( userNumberOfPackages < 100 ){
        subTotal = packagePrice * userNumberOfPackages;
        discount = ( (double)40/100) * subTotal;
        total = subTotal - discount;

    } else{
        subTotal = packagePrice * userNumberOfPackages;
        discount = ( (double)50/100) * subTotal;
        total = subTotal - discount;
    }

    userOutput = String.format( "Packages purchased: \nSubtotal: $\nDiscount: $\nTotal: $", userNumberOfPackages, subTotal,
            discount, total);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, userOutput);

    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

Comment: a) Usually there's a line number associated with the error message. Please mark the line that is mentioned. b) Your code can be reduced until you get a [MCVE]. Do that for us. We don't like reading dozens of lines of code if the problem can be expressed in 5 lines.

Comment: at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4302)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Formatter.java:2806)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2753)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2520)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455)
        at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2940)
        at SoftwareSales.main(SoftwareSales.java:45)

Comment: Can you show me how you would edit the program to fix it?

Comment: I am not sure. I think it is just saying the program will not execute.

Comment: Yes, I know it is that line. I just don't know how to change it so it works out

Comment: what is your expectation?  there will be no error in happy scenario

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to exist any more.

Answer (score 0):

Let's sum up the comments, since they will not only fix your problem but describe the procedure for any problem.

1. Get *all* the exception information. That is type, message and callstack.
2. Look at the call stack and identify the topmost class you have written yourself.
3. Get the line number.
4. Look at that line and think of potential issues.

Applied to your case:

```
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4302) at
java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Formatter.java:2806) at
java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2753) at
java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2520) at
java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455) at
java.lang.String.format(String.java:2940) at 
SoftwareSales.main(SoftwareSales.java:45)
```

Only SoftwareSales.java was written by yourself. So the problem is in SoftwareSales.java, line 45.

It's this line:

```
userOutput = String.format( "Packages purchased: \nSubtotal: $\nDiscount: $\nTotal: $", userNumberOfPackages, subTotal,
            discount, total);
```

With `String.format()` you want to insert 4 numbers into a string. But where should they be inserted? There's no placehoder.

Looking at some [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-):

> format: a format string

And [a format string](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) needs something with a `%`. Likely `%f`for floating point and `%d` for decimal.

Finally (untested):

```
userOutput = String.format( "Packages purchased: %d\n
       Subtotal: $%f\n
       Discount: $%f\n
       Total: $%f", 
       userNumberOfPackages, subTotal, discount, total);
```

Comment: I am still getting the same problem with your code.